# Image shrinks in responsive view with tailwind

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css

So I am working on a project with React and Tailwind. I have a component that has an image and text and on small screens I have it laid out like so.

[image]

The component is the card under the word "Events". This looks exactly how I want it to look and on larger screens I want it to be more horizontal like so:

[image]

So these 2 are exactly how I want. The issue is, when I resize the window, there is a size (maybe between md and sm) where the image shrinks and doesnt fill the card, here is an image of it happening

[image]

So you can see the image height only takes up around 2/3 of the height of the card, maybe in this instance I can change the width of the image to be half of the card but I have attempted and cannot do it.

Below is the code for the component:

```
<div className='flex flex-col w-auto bg-white border border-gray-500 rounded-t-xl overflow-hidden lg:flex-row md:rounded-xl'>
                {/* Image Container */}
                <div className='xs:w-full lg:w-1/4'>
                    <img className='object-cover' src={event.featured_image} alt={event.title} />
                </div>
                {/* Content Container */}
                <div className="flex flex-col justify-between p-2">
                    {/* Content */}
                    <div>
                        <p className='text-xl text-blue-700 font-semibold'>{event.title}</p>
                        <p className='py-2 text-gray-700'>{event.description}</p>
                    </div>
                    <div className='pt-8 sm:pt-0'>
                        <p className='text-sm text-blue-500'>{event.start_date}{event.end_date ? ` - ${event.end_date}` : ''}</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Add `flex-shrink-0` [class](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/flex-shrink#don-t-shrink) to prevent image from shrinking

```
<div className='xs:w-full lg:w-1/4 flex-shrink-0'>
    <img className='object-cover' src={event.featured_image} alt={event.title} />
</div>
```

Comment: This didnt have any difference

Comment: Add 'w-full h-full' to img tag